# Problems getting all customer records from KashFlow API

Tags: php, arrays

I've done most of the leg work already. I've connected to the API and it's returning an array of customer objects, I'm just struggling with how to loop through each customer object.

Here is what the the structure that the API call is returning:

```
stdClass Object
(
[Customer] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CustomerID] => 20409125
                [Name] => Computer Says No
                [Telephone] => 
                [Mobile] => 
                [Email] => myemail@address.com
                [Website] => 
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CustomerID] => 20409126
                [Name] => Joe Bloggs
                [Telephone] => 
                [Mobile] => 
                [Email] => myemail@address.com
                [Website] => 
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [CustomerID] => 20409127
                [Name] => Jane Bloggs
                [Telephone] => 
                [Mobile] => 
                [Email] => myemail@address.com
                [Website] => 
            )
    )
)
```

And here's how I'm trying to loop through the response

```
$kashflow = new Kashflow('my username','my password');
$customers = $kashflow->getCustomers();

foreach($customers as $customer){
echo "<pre>";
print_r($customer->CustomerID);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

If I `print_r($customers)` I get:

```
stdClass Object
(
[GetCustomersResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Customer] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [CustomerID] => 20409125
                    )
                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [CustomerID] => 20409126
                    )
                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [CustomerID] => 20409127
                    )
              )
      )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$kashflow = new Kashflow('my username','my password');
$customers = $kashflow->getCustomers();

foreach($customers->GetCustomersResult->Customer as $customer){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($customer->CustomerID);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: No luck, I get
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Customer and
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: What do you get if you print_r($customers); before the foreach? could you post what is output?

Comment: sure it's

stdClass Object
(
    [GetCustomersResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Customer] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [CustomerID] => 20409125

Comment: That's it!! After posting the result with GetCustomerResult it became apparent where I was going wrong! Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @MNelmes - glad I could help! if it works for you could you mark is as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting record like

```
    $first_id= array_column($customers, 'cust_id');
    foreach($first_id as $id)
    {
      echo "<pre>";
      echo $id;
      echo "</pre>"
    }
```